# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input -- HTML Element Deletion in JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to create this form where I can have a button which will add a duplicate, and a button that will delete the current 'new form'. All functionality is working aside from the removal of the form-- I'm trying to use JQuery's .remove function but this error began presenting itself as soon as I added it.

I'm almost 100% certain that all parentheses/brackets are aligned-- I ran it through several linting sites to make sure.

Any ideas from looking at the javascript portion of the code?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add a New Course</title>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            }

            .buttonHolder {
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadXMLDoc_makeCatArray()">
        <form action="" id="courseForm">
            <div class = "div1">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Enter course info:</legend>
                    Course title: <br>
                    <input type="text" id="displayName1" value=""><br>
                    Category: <br>
                    <select name="categoryDropdown" id="category1"></select><br>
                    Duration: <br>
                    <input type="time" id="duration1" value=""><br>
                    Subcategory: <br>
                    <input type="text" id="subcategory1" value=""><br>
                    Description: <br>
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="60" id="description1"></textarea><br>
                    URL: <br>
                    <input type="text" id="url1" value=""><br>
                    ID: <br>
                    <input type="text" id="id1" value=""><br>
                    Table ID: <br>
                    <input type="text" id="tableId1" value=""><br>
                    <div class="buttonHolder">
                        <input type="button" value="Submit All" onclick="javascript: loadXMLDoc();">
                        <input type="button" value="New Course" onclick="javascript: addCourseForm();">
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </form>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://splm.sharepoint.com/sites/OCB/Shared%20Documents/Testing/js/vkbeautify.js"></script>
    <script src="https://splm.sharepoint.com/sites/OCB/Shared%20Documents/Testing/js/MicrosoftAjaxCore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/sharepointplus@5.1.0/sharepointplus-5.1.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        //Initialize the number of forms being submitted as 1
        var count = 1;

        function addCourseForm()
        {
            //Get the course form element
            var course = document.getElementById("courseForm");

            //Error checking here, making sure we got courseForm
            if (course)
            {
                //Create a new <div> element which contains the form
                var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
                newDiv.className = "div" + (count + 1);
                var divName = "div" + (count + 1);
                newDiv.innerHTML = '<fieldset> <legend>Enter course info:</legend> Course title: <br> <input type="text" id="courseTitle' + (count + 1) + '"><br> Category: <br> <select name="categoryDropdown" id="category' + (count + 1) + '" value=""></select><br> Duration: <br> <input type="time" id="duration' + (count + 1) + '" value=""><br> Subcategory: <br> <input type="text" id="subcategory' + (count + 1) + '" value=""><br> Description: <br> <textarea rows="4" cols="60" id="description' + (count + 1) + '"></textarea><br> URL: <br><input type="text" id="url' + (count + 1) + '" value=""><br> <div class="buttonHolder"> <input type="button" value="Submit All" onclick="javascript: loadXMLDoc();"> <input type="button" value="New Course" onclick="javascript: addCourseForm();"> <input type="button" value="Remove Course" onclick="removeCourseForm(' + divName + ');"> </div> </fieldset>';

                //Appends the new <p> element to the other forms
                course.appendChild(newDiv);

                //Add one to the number of forms being submitted
                count++;

                loadXMLDoc_makeCatArray();
            }
        }

        function removeCourseForm(paragraph) {
            $("." + paragraph).remove();
            count--;
        }

        function loadXMLDoc_submitFormData() {
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        submitFormData(this);
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://splm.sharepoint.com/sites/OCB/Shared%20Documents/Testing/curriculumdata.xml", true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }

        function submitFormData(xml)
        {
            var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;

            console.log(xmlDoc);

            for (var x = 1; x <= count; x ++) {
                var p = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("course")[1];
                var p_prime = p.cloneNode(false);
                xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("curriculumdata")[0].appendChild(p_prime);
                var br = xmlDoc.createElement("br");

                var elements = ["category", "description", "displayName", "duration", "id", "subcategory", "tableId", "url"];
                for (var y = 0; y < elements.length; y++){
                    console.log(elements[y] + x);
                    newElement = xmlDoc.createElement(elements[y]);
                    if (y == 0) {
                        newText = xmlDoc.createTextNode(document.getElementById(elements[y] + x).text);
                    } else {
                        newText = xmlDoc.createTextNode(document.getElementById(elements[y] + x).value);
                    }
                    newElement.appendChild(newText);
                    console.log(newElement);
                    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("course")[xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("course").length - 1].appendChild(newElement);
                }
            };

            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('https://splm.sharepoint.com/sites/OCB');
            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Course List');

            var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
            this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
 
            var documents = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc.documentElement);
            documents = vkbeautify.xml(documents);
            oListItem.set_item('xml_data', documents);

            oListItem.update();

            clientContext.load(oListItem);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        };
        function onQuerySucceeded() {
            alert('Course successfully added');
        }
        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }


        function loadXMLDoc_makeCatArray() {
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        catArray(this);
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://splm.sharepoint.com/sites/OCB/Shared%20Documents/curriculumdata.xml", true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }

        
        function catArray(xml){
            eleArray = [];

            var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;

            ele = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("course");

            for (i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
            if(!(eleArray.includes(ele[i].getElementsByTagName("category")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue))){

                eleArray.push(ele[i].getElementsByTagName("category")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                }
            }
            var sel = document.getElementsByName('categoryDropdown')[count - 1];
            for(var i = 0; i < eleArray.length; i++) {
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.innerHTML = eleArray[i];
                opt.value = eleArray[i];
                console.log(opt);
                sel.appendChild(opt);
            }
        };
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI: With inline event handlers, like `onclick="javascript: loadXMLDoc();"` you should remove `javascript; ` and just have `onclick="loadXMLDoc();"`. Better yet, don't use inline handlers at all and do all your event binding in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your HTML is not valid because you cannot have anything after `</body>` except `</html>`. All that scripting should be moved to just before the closing `body` tag. Additionally, it's invalid to nest a `fieldset` in a `p`. You could make that `p` a `div`.

Next, `count --;` needs to be `count--;`

The unexpected input is the space after the `count` variable reference.

And your manually built HTML string needs to be looked at because you have nested double quotes in double quotes and you are concatenating nothing after `count`:

`onclick="javascript: removeCourseForm("p' + count + '");">`

This would also result in the same error because you have a trailing `+` but then nothing to concatenate it to.

**Having said that....You really shouldn't be taking this approach in the first place.**

Instead of creating an huge string of concatenated HTML (which is where your issue lies), just clone the first fieldset. Now, because we're going to clone, we want to get away from using `id` attributes and instead use `.querySelector()` and `.querySelectorAll()` to find elements based on CSS selectors.

You also should stop using `.getElementsByTagName()` because it has performance impact and you aren't interested in the collection that it returns anyway, you are passing an index to the collection. Instead use `.querySelector()`.

Lastly, don't use inline event handlers (`onclick`). Do you event binding in JavaScript.

See the comments below.

Here's a working example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Add a New Course</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        }
        
        .buttonHolder {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" id="courseForm">

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Enter course info:</legend>
            Course title:
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="displayName">
            <br> Category:
            <br>
            <select name="categoryDropdown" class="category"></select>
            <br> Duration:
            <br>
            <input type="time" class="duration">
            <br> Subcategory:
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="subcategory">
            <br> Description:
            <br>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="60" class="description"></textarea>
            <br> URL:
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="url1">
            <br> ID:
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="id1">
            <br> Table ID:
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="tableId1">
            <br>
            <div class="buttonHolder">
                <input type="button" value="Submit All" class="submitAll">
                <input type="button" value="New Course" class="newCourse">
            </div>
        </fieldset>

    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://splm.sharepoint.com/sites/OCB/Shared%20Documents/Testing/js/vkbeautify.js"></script>
    <script src="https://splm.sharepoint.com/sites/OCB/Shared%20Documents/Testing/js/MicrosoftAjaxCore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/sharepointplus@5.1.0/sharepointplus-5.1.js"></script>

    <script>
        //Get the course form element
        var course = document.getElementById("courseForm");
        
        document.querySelector(".submitAll").addEventListener("click", loadXMLDoc_submitFormData);
                document.querySelector(".newCourse").addEventListener("click", addCourseForm);

        function addCourseForm() {

            var firstFS = document.querySelector("fieldset");

            //Error checking here, making sure we got courseForm
            if (course) {
                // >>> **** Clone the current fieldset ***** <<<<
                var newFS = firstFS.cloneNode(true);

                // Create and configure remove button
                var removeBtn = document.createElement("button");
                removeBtn.textContent = "Remove Course";
                removeBtn.type = "button";
                removeBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    // Call the remove function but pass the fieldset
                    // that this button is part of
                    removeCourseForm(this.closest("fieldset"));
                });

                // Append the new button to the new fieldset
                newFS.querySelector("div.buttonHolder").appendChild(removeBtn);

                //Appends the new <p> element to the other forms
                course.appendChild(newFS);
                // ***********************************************

                loadXMLDoc_makeCatArray();
            }
        }

        function removeCourseForm(fs) {
            fs.remove();
        }

        function loadXMLDoc_submitFormData() {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    submitFormData(this);
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://splm.sharepoint.com/sites/OCB/Shared%20Documents/Testing/curriculumdata.xml", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }

        function submitFormData(xml) {
            var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;

            console.log(xmlDoc);

            for (var x = 1; x <= count; x++) {
                var p = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("course")[1];
                var p_prime = p.cloneNode(false);
                xmlDoc.querySelector("curriculumdata").appendChild(p_prime);
                var br = xmlDoc.createElement("br");

                var elements = ["category", "description", "displayName", "duration", "id", "subcategory", "tableId", "url"];
                for (var y = 0; y < elements.length; y++) {
                    console.log(elements[y] + x);
                    newElement = xmlDoc.createElement(elements[y]);
                    if (y == 0) {
                        newText = xmlDoc.createTextNode(document.getElementById(elements[y] + x).text);
                    } else {
                        newText = xmlDoc.createTextNode(document.getElementById(elements[y] + x).value);
                    }
                    newElement.appendChild(newText);
                    console.log(newElement);
                    xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("course")[xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("course").length - 1].appendChild(newElement);
                }
            };

            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('https://splm.sharepoint.com/sites/OCB');
            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Course List');

            var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
            this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

            var documents = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc.documentElement);
            documents = vkbeautify.xml(documents);
            oListItem.set_item('xml_data', documents);

            oListItem.update();

            clientContext.load(oListItem);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        };

        function onQuerySucceeded() {
            alert('Course successfully added');
        }

        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }

        function loadXMLDoc_makeCatArray() {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    catArray(this);
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://splm.sharepoint.com/sites/OCB/Shared%20Documents/curriculumdata.xml", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }

        function catArray(xml) {
            eleArray = [];

            var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;

            ele = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("course");

            for (i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
                if (!(eleArray.includes(ele[i].querySelector("category").childNodes[0].nodeValue))) {

                    eleArray.push(ele[i].querySelector("category").childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                }
            }
            var sel = document.querySelector('categoryDropdown')[count - 1];
            for (var i = 0; i < eleArray.length; i++) {
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.innerHTML = eleArray[i];
                opt.value = eleArray[i];
                console.log(opt);
                sel.appendChild(opt);
            }
        };
        
        loadXMLDoc_makeCatArray();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If true, should we not close as typo?

Comment: Ahh, good catch! That probably contributed to the error but I'm still getting the same message after remedying that... I'm assuming it's got something to do with the way I'm calling removeCourseForm?

Comment: @bean03 See my updated answer. You've also got problems with your HTML string.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm assuming my problem lies in that call somewhere, yeah; I've got the weird nesting going on because that whole line is being put as innerHTML so it's inside of single quotes... the concatenation there should be adding the ");"> </div> </fieldset>  to the end of the call. That line is certainly a bit of a mess.

Comment: @bean03 Take another look. I've eliminated the previous error and now it complains that `p1` doesn't exist, but without knowing the details of your tag names, I'm not sure what it should be.

Comment: @ScottMarcus that's the issue I'm running into now as well. That tag name should be p2 (I fixed that by just setting that count to be count + 1)-- essentially the code creates a new p element which is followed by the count value to denote which iteration of the form it is. Unless I'm using the class of the element incorrectly perhaps? Can I not pass that as an argument in a function?

Comment: Since it's not a variable I'm thinking it needs to be inside of those double quotes which just brings us back to the 'unexpected end of input' error

Comment: @ScottMarcus thank you so much for your help so far-- I appreciate it immensely! I updated the code in the snippet to match your recommendations. Still facing the same issue as before. Really not sure what's going on with this function!

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up fixing this problem rather simply:

I called the function removeCourseForm() without any parameters, and then generated the div name inside of that function.

```
function removeCourseForm() {
        var divName = "div" + count;
        $("." + divName).remove();
        count--;
    }
```

This seems to have remedied the whole issue and it works nicely now :)